# Haskell. Im confused how this code snippet works

Tags: haskell

```
magnitude :: Floating a => [a] -> a
magnitude = sqrt . mag
  where mag [] = 0
        mag (x:xs) = x^2 + mag xs
```

This is supposed to square every element in the list, then take their sum and then take the square root. Fair enough, but how does this recursive function work, when it only adds x to the list xs ?

Comment: `x` is the head (first element) of the list, and it uses recursion on the tail `xs`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but how does this recursive function work, when it only adds `x` to the list `xs`?

`x` is the head (first element) of the list, and it uses recursion on the tail `xs`.

So for example for a list `[1,4,2,5]`, it obtain the sum with:

```
mag [1,4,2,5]
    = 1 ^ 2 + mag [4,2,5]
    = 1 + mag [4,2,5]
    = 1 + (4 ^ 2 + mag [2,5])
    = 1 + (16 + mag [2,5])
    = 1 + (16 + (2 ^ 2 + mag [5]))
    = 1 + (16 + (4 + mag [5]))
    = 1 + (16 + (4 + (5 ^ 2 + mag [])))
    = 1 + (16 + (4 + (25 + mag [])))
    = 1 + (16 + (4 + (25 + 0)))
    = 1 + (16 + (4 + 25))
    = 1 + (16 + 29)
    = 1 + 45
    = 46
```

The `magnitude` is defined as `sqrt . mag`, this is equivalent to `\x -> sqrt (mag x)`. This thus means that we first calculate the sum of squares of `x` with `mag x`, and then calculate the square root of that result.

Answer (score 4):

> This is supposed to square every element in the list, then take their sum

This is done by the local function, `mag`.

```
mag [] = 0
mag (x:xs) = x^2 + mag xs
```

If the list is empty, the sum of squares is 0. If it is non-empty, it is the square of the first element plus the sum of squares of the remainder of the list.

> and then take the square root.

This is done by `magnitude`. Its definition is equivalent to

```
magnitude xs = sqrt (mag xs)
```

But we use function composition, `.`,

```
magnitude xs = (sqrt.mag) xs
```

and pointfree style (omitting the `xs` since it appears on both the left and right side) for brevity

```
magnitude = sqrt.mag
```